# Posting messages for intended location Android application

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-intent

I am new to android programming and I am trying to create an application that helps me to send a message/post (based on intended location) to those users using the same app in that particular location. 
Can i get some resources on this? 
Also currently i am trying to implement the feature wherein i post a message about a particular location on my wall and that same message has to seen by the users in that location. How can i implement this. 
please post suggestions/open-srouce codes, examples etc. 
thank you

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for solutions related to the [Geo-Fences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geo-fence) concept.

There are plenty of applications that can use your mobile coordinates to interact and provide feedback. Notice that the accuracy of the mobile phone GPS is not THAT good, but people can play :-)

Take a look on this application -- https://www.onx.ms/#!landingPage

Official Android docs about geofencing here -- http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/training/location/geofencing.html